# Insert parsed HTML in ColumnText

Tags: c#, itext

I've looked for a solution to insert parsed HTML in `ColumnText`, but I haven't found any solution.

I have a HTML text as:

```
String text = '<p>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>';
```

And I need to insert it into a `ColumnText`:

```
PdfContentByte content = ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(text);
ColumnText cb = new ColumnText(content);
```

The result in PDF file must be:

Hello **world**!

Have you got any idea to implement `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(String text)` method?

Comment: While it is easy to parse HTML and draw it in a `ColumnText`, your method `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(String text)` returning a `PdfContentByte` does not make sense. What shall `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText` do to return a `PdfContentByte` only based on a HTML `String`?

Comment: The method `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText` would parsing the html string and generate the correct object to insert in ColumnText and show as rich text in PDF.

Comment: *"generate the correct object to insert in ColumnText"* - that would be possible, but you want it to return a `PdfContentByte` instead on which you want to construct a `ColumnText`.

Comment: No, I don't need necessarily a `PdfContentBye`object. The returned object by `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText` would be the right type that ColumnText() requires. The solution couldn't be as simple as I have suggested? (using only one method).

Comment: *"No, I don't need necessarily a `PdfContentByte` object."* - Ah, ok, then I was misled by the `PdfContentByte content = ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(text);` line in your question. *"The solution couldn't be as simple as I have suggested? (using only one method)."* - Yes, it can, if that method can return a `List<IElement>`, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(String text)` returning a `PdfContentByte` does not make sense, after all the method only has the `String text` to work with, no `PdfWriter` or `PdfContentByte`.

A method `ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(String text)` returning elements to later add to a `ColumnText`, on the other hand, does make sense, e.g.

```
List<IElement> ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(String text)
{
    ListElementHandler listHandler = new ListElementHandler();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(listHandler, new StringReader(text));
    return listHandler.List;
}
```

using this custom `IElementHandler` implementation

```
public class ListElementHandler : IElementHandler
{
    List<IElement> elements = new List<IElement>();

    public List<IElement> List => elements;

    public void Add(IWritable w)
    {
        if (w is WritableElement)
        {
            foreach (IElement e in ((WritableElement)w).Elements())
            {
                elements.Add(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can be used to retrieve elements which later can be added to a `ColumnText` like this

```
String text = "<p>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>";
List<IElement> parsedText = ConvertToHtmlForColumnText(text);

using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4))
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(result, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();

    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Bottom, document.Right, document.Top);
    ct.Add(parsedText);
    ct.Go();
}
```

using this custom extension for syntactic sugar

```
public static class ColumnTextListExtension
{
    public static void Add(this ColumnText ct, List<IElement> elements)
    {
        foreach (IElement e in elements)
        {
            ct.AddElement(e);
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I will try your solution.